# How to cut intervals of lines of a file and put them into multiple files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a fasta file containing ids and sequences like this:

```
>4S3O_2:C
GSMSQAVQTNGTQPLSKTWELSLYELQRTPQEAITDGLEIVVSPRSLHSELMCPICLDMLKNTMTTKECLHRFCADCIITALRSGNKECPTCRKKLVSKRSLRPDPNFDALISKIYPS
>5JH8_1:A
AAMVLAYYSGYAGNYAALTRYAASFNAVAVDFYNITAQGAVTGNGDPAPNDAISFLLGRKIPAYGCVSNVDGNGNWSADIAHAVSTSAQSQAVANLVKFAQDKRFSGINVDFEAVAQGDRNNFSHFI
```

I want to recursively cut the lines containing the ids and the sequences and put them into new multiple files named after the corresponding ids (chains excluded) so like the newfile cointains

```
>4S3O_2:C
GSMSQAVQTNGTQPLSKTWELSLYELQRTPQEAITDGLEIVVSPRSLHSELMCPICLDMLKNTMTTKECLHRFCADCIITALRSGNKECPTCRKKLVSKRSLRPDPNFDALISKIYPS
```

and It's named `4S30_2.fasta`

This is what I tried:

```
awk -F ">" | sed -i -e '$0,$1{w file.fasta d}' BlindSet150.fasta
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a robust bioinformatics tool for extracting fasta sequences to individual files, but if you want to roll your own with awk I'd suggest something like

```
awk -F '[>:]' '/^>/ {close(f); f = $2 ".fasta" } f {print > f}' BlindSet150.fasta
```